# Using Java BigDecimal still not correctly solving

Tags: java, math, double, bigdecimal

I have a method with two `double` values being inputted. When trying to add them together I get incorrect values over a certain threshold so I started using `BigDecimal`.

However even with `BigDecimal` I still have incorrect values?

```
double value1 = 2789.45;
double value2 = 557.89;
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(value1 + value2));
```

prints

```
3347.3399999999997
```

when It should read as

```
3347.34
```

How can I do this correctly even if `value1` and `value2` could be higher than current scope? (they are calculated in a separate method).

Should I just use rounding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should I just use rounding?

**NOPE**, what you are experiencing is lose of precision of `double` sum.

---

You are suming the doubles first (`value1 + value2`) and after converting the double sum (which has lost precision) to a `BigDecimal`.

To avoid this use this instead:

```
double value1 = 2789.45;
double value2 = 557.89;
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(value1).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(value2)));
```

OUTPUT:

```
3347.34
```

Working [IDEONE DEMO here](https://ideone.com/UDcdA3)

---

**UPDATE**

> -1. Instead of using `BigDecimal.valueOf`, which is still fragile, you should be using `BigDecimal` from the beginning and create them with `new BigDecimal("2789.45")`, `new BigDecimal("557.89")`. As soon as you've used a `double` literal, you've introduced imprecision. `BigDecimal.valueOf` tries to get it back, but it doesn't always work. – [`Louis Wasserman`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman)

Actually I'm not totally agree with this. You cannot hardcode the values creating new decimals, what I can be agree is to read the values (if possible for the OP) in a `String` directly to avoid `double` precision lost:

```
String value1 = "2789.45"; 
BigDecimal one = new BigDecimal(value1);
String value2 = "557.89";
BigDecimal two = new BigDecimal(value2);
System.out.println(one.add(two));
```

OUTPUT:

```
3347.34
```

This will avoid the problems [`Louis Wasserman`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman) is noticing.

NEW WORKING DEMO

Comment: Heh you beat me to it :)

Comment: -1.  Instead of using `BigDecimal.valueOf`, which is still fragile, you should be using `BigDecimal` from the beginning and create them with `new BigDecimal("2789.45")`, `new BigDecimal("557.89")`.  _As soon as you've used a `double` literal, you've introduced imprecision._  `BigDecimal.valueOf` tries to get it back, but it doesn't always work.

Comment: @LouisWasserman You're assuming I'm creating declaring these values indefinitely. In the question they are just arbitrary values which are products of other methods. I declared them as variables here to help with the example and not to overload the question with hundreds of lines of irrelevant code.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, you are proposing to hardcode the values instead of using variables? You can propose to read variables in a `String`, and I will be agree to avoid double rounding.... but *harcoding them*? this **is never a good idea**.

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler will evaluate the sum first, it adds the two `doubles` first and hence you losing the precision, you essentially doing this

```
double value1 = 2789.45;
double value2 = 557.89;
double sum = value1 + value2; // precision lost here
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(sum));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have already lost precision when you assign the variables to doubles.

Consider this program:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(2789.45));
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("2789.45"));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
2789.4499999999998181010596454143524169921875
2789.45
```

Doing the addition in BigDecimal will get you the exact sum of the inputs, but if you first convert to `double` the inputs will be the closest doubles to the values you wrote.